# Как называют человека, которому нужно считать минуты?

Tags: терминология, профессии

Как называют людей, которым нужно считать минуты?
Есть ли какая-нибудь профессия, в которой необходимо считать по минутам?
(Например, мы говорим: 5 часов и пять минут; они представляют это как 305 минут.)

Comment: Ну, и раньше для подобных действий хватало образование уровня церковно-приходской школы, а сейчас тем более проще написать программку (да даже просто бумажки-напоминалки хватит) для этого, чем нанимать отдельного человека для задачи с которой справится любой второклассник

Comment: Вопрос сформулирован, увы, неясно. Думаю, он о профессиях, которые оперириуют временем, измеренным всегда в минутах.

Answer (score 2):

Не уверен, что сильно распространена нынче (и есть ли вообще?) эта творческая профессия, но раньше, руководствуясь *нормами*, учётом рабочего времени,  в том числе пооперационно, занимался *нормировщик*. Возможно, что она скоро вновь будет актуальна.

Answer (score 0):

**хронометри́ст** *м.*
Тот, кто занимается хронометражом; хронометражист.
[**Толковый словарь Ефремовой**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/264401/%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82)

**хронометрист**
Лицо, ответственное за отсчет времени на соревнованиях.
[**Справочник технического переводчика**](https://technical_translator_dictionary.academic.ru/266344/%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82)

ХРОНОМЕТРАЖ — метод изучения затрат времени на непосредственное выполнение заданной операции путем наблюдения и измерения циклически повторяющихся ее элементов (частей).
[**Большой Энциклопедический словарь**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc3p/318438/%D0%A5%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%96)

Хронометрист (хронометражист), учетчик рабочего времени, нормировщик, фотограф рабочего дня, секундометрист — названий много, всё зависит от места и особенностей счёта времени, замеры которого производятся при помощи **хронометра**.
Он имеет вид и в основном устройство карманных часов, но с большой, во весь циферблат, секундной стрелкой и маленькой минутной (**часовая стрелка отсутствует**).

В астрономии, в современном морском деле, в космонавтике, в ядерной физике, в ракетных войсках счёт времени идет уже не на минуты и даже не на секунды. Вполне возможно, что там и названия профессий могут быть другими.
[**Точный атомный хронометр**](https://hi-news.ru/science/samyj-tochnyj-atomnyj-xronometr-teryaet-odnu-sekundu-za-pyat-milliardov-let.html)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то речь идет о ситуации, в которой основной единицей времени является минута.

Вряд ли такая профессия есть. В науке и технике основной единицей является секунда, в астрономии помимо секунды - год, галактический год.

Может кто и "считает минутами", но это явно не профессиональный принцип, а ситуация - у медиков, например.